# Python simple project not quite working

Tags: python

```
# program to test truth tables v2

import time 
import sys

x = 0

while x == 0:
    x = str(raw_input("Please enter True or False..."))
    x = x[0].upper()+ x[1:]

    if x == "True":  
        x = True
    elif x == "False":
        x = False
    else:
        print 'invalid input!'
        x = 0 # very difficult but this works now!

print x

y = 0

while y == 0:
    y = str(raw_input("Please enter True or False again..."))
    y = y[0].upper()+ y[1:]

    if y == "True":
        y = True
    elif y == "False":
        y = False
    else:
        print 'invalid input!'
        y = 0

problem = 0
while problem == 0:
    problem = input("Please enter number: \n1 for AND, 2 for OR, 3 for NAND, 4 for NOR...")
    if problem == 1:
        print "I'm thinking.."
        time.sleep(2.5) 
        print "the answer is..."
        time.sleep(1.0) 
        print x, "AND", y, "is", x and y 

    elif problem == 2:
        print "I'm thinking.."
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print "the answer is..."
        time.sleep(1)
        print x, "OR", y, "is", x or y

    elif problem == 3:
        print "I'm thinking.."
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print "the answer is..."
        time.sleep(1)
        print x, "NAND", y, "is", not(x and y) # not working for false/false or false/true

    elif problem == 4:
        print "I'm thinking.."
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print "the answer is..."
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print x, "NOR", y, "is", not(x or y) # not working for false/false
    else:
        print 'invalid input'
        problem = 0
```

**I thought this project worked then once I had tested all the combos, I found that there is a problem with the elif in the first while loop. See the comments in the last section. Any help gratefully received**

Comment: This is not really a question. It would be easier for everyone if you posted a specific question / scenario you're trying.

Comment: can you explain the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `ast.literal_eval(raw_input("Please enter True or False...")`?  Then it would return `True` or `False` directly without having to go through an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your first while loop is that 0 == False. Toss that in the interpreter and see.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess.  You need to turn your booleans into strings.  For example, in the first `while loop`, you set x equal to `True` and `False` instead of "True" and "False." Because Python sees booleans `True` and `False` as 1 and 0, respectively, your `while` loop variables (x and y) remain equal to zero in the case of False.  It's likely causing you to repeat whenever the user inputs `False`

Try it and see.  Let me know.  And whatever you do, keep practicing!!  You'll get it.

EDIT:  Yep that was the problem.  Here's your working code.

```
import time 
import sys

x = 0

while x == 0:
    x = str(raw_input("Please enter True or False..."))
    #x = x[0].upper()+ x[1:]
    print "THIS IS X: {}".format(x)

    if x == "True":  
        x = "True"
    elif x == "False":
        x = "False"
    else:
        print 'invalid input!'
        x = 0 # very difficult but this works now!

print x

y = 0

while y == 0:
    y = str(raw_input("Please enter True or False again..."))
    y = y[0].upper()+ y[1:]

    if y == "True":
        y = "True"
    elif y == "False":
        y = "False"
    else:
        print 'invalid input!'
        y = 0

problem = 0
while problem == 0:
    problem = input("Please enter number: \n1 for AND, 2 for OR, 3 for NAND, 4 for NOR...")
    if problem == 1:
        print "I'm thinking.."
        time.sleep(2.5) 
        print "the answer is..."
        time.sleep(1.0) 
        print x, "AND", y, "is", x and y 

    elif problem == 2:
        print "I'm thinking.."
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print "the answer is..."
        time.sleep(1)
        print x, "OR", y, "is", x or y

    elif problem == 3:
        print "I'm thinking.."
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print "the answer is..."
        time.sleep(1)
        print x, "NAND", y, "is", not(x and y) # not working for false/false or false/true

    elif problem == 4:
        print "I'm thinking.."
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print "the answer is..."
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print x, "NOR", y, "is", not(x or y) # not working for false/false
    else:
        print 'invalid input'
        problem = 0
```

Comment: also, OP, re: your line to capitalize the user's input (i.e., `y[0].upper()+ y[1:]`), you can just use `variable.title()`.  As discussed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)

Answer (score 1):

The other posters have it right -- Python sees 0 and False as the same thing, at least truth-wise. We humans know that they are not the same thing type-wise, of course, and you can force Python to tell the difference by using "is" instead of "==", so the line should become...

```
while y is 0: # <-- change that line there
    y = str(raw_input("Please enter True or False again..."))
    y = y[0].upper()+ y[1:]
```

This is a "strict comparison" that compares both the value (which Python thinks are the same) and type (False is a Boolean, 0 is a Number)